# How can I change the color of my output in my PHP Calculator?

Tags: php, html, css

I can't figure out what to target to change my output to a different color besides black. I was thinking maybe operator but I'm not really sure. Couldn't find anywhere on here with this question so here I am. I know you can fix this issue by using Javascript but I'm not looking to do that. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Calculator</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form method="POST" action="calculator.php">

    <h1>PHP Calculator</h1>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num1" placeholder="Number 1"><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num2" placeholder="Number 2"><br>

    <select name="operator">
        <option>None</option>
        <option>Add</option>
        <option>Subtract</option>
        <option>Multiply</option>
        <option>Divide</option>
    </select>
        <br>

<button name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">Calculate</button>




</form>
```

```
<p>The answer is:</p>







<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $result1 = $_POST['num1'];
        $result2 = $_POST['num2'];
        $operator = $_POST['operator'];




        switch ($operator) {
            case "None":
            echo "You need to select a method!";
            break;

            case "Add":
            echo $result1 + $result2;
            break;

            case "Subtract":
            echo $result1 - $result2;
            break;

            case "Multiply":
            echo $result1 * $result2;
            break;

            case "Divide":
            echo $result1 / $result2;
            break;

        }

    }


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the color to depend on the output? If you want one and the same color for all output, you can simply use inline CSS. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles) - it has an example for how to make text blue.

Comment: Finn, I want the color to be the same every time it's outputed to the screen, but I don't know what to target to make that happen. The answers below did not work at all. People tell me this is easy but no one has given me an answer....

Comment: I added an answer to show how to wrap the `<?php ... ?>` code in an HTML attribute and add inline CSS to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472007/6451879

Answer (score 1):

Put the php around some html tag like  or  and then give it css attributes like:

```
<a style="color:red;"> <?php // php calculator here ?> </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your echo statement you can wrap the text in HTML tags and then use CSS.

PHP:

```
$result = $result1 + $result2;
echo "<span class='output'>" . $result . "</span>";
```

CSS:

`<style>    .output{      color:blue;      }    </style>`

Comment: That doesn't work because this is the error I get:



Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php-projects/calculator/calculator.php on line 64

Comment: @DanielD Sorry for the delayed response, I missed that there. Try the edited answer that should work. If not let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one and the same color for all output, you can simply use inline CSS. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles) - it has an example for how to make text blue.

```php
<p>The answer is:</p>

<p style="color: blue;">

  <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $result1 = $_POST['num1'];
      $result2 = $_POST['num2'];
      $operator = $_POST['operator'];

      switch ($operator) {
        case "None":
        echo "You need to select a method!";
        break;

        case "Add":
        echo $result1 + $result2;
        break;

        case "Subtract":
        echo $result1 - $result2;
        break;

        case "Multiply":
        echo $result1 * $result2;
        break;

        case "Divide":
        echo $result1 / $result2;
        break;

      }

    }

  ?>

</p>
```

The key is to wrap your answer in an HTML tag (such as `<p>` or `<span>` or `<div>`) and adding `style="color: red;"`.